# register a font with Tcl/Tk (via VBScript)

Tags: windows, vbscript, fonts, tcl

I'm trying to use a custom font in a Tcl/Tk GUI, running on Windows.

I don't really want to install the font system-wide (as this would require admin privileges), so it seems that I need to somehow use the [AddFontResourceEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-at/en-en/library/windows/desktop/dd183327(v=vs.85).aspx) function, to register the font (temporarily)

Now there are a few complications:

- needs to be able to run with Tcl/Tk 8.5
- must run (at least) on W7 to W10
- pure Tcl/Tk solution (no binary extension; any solution must be self-contained with a Tcl/Tk interpreter and with whatever interpreters a pristine W32 installation comes with)
- no admin privileges on the deployment machines
- no user interaction

So I was thinking on using a VBS script that would do some magical incantations to call `AddFontResourceEx`. (Originally I though of using a Powershell script, only to discover that Powershell scripting seems to be  disabled by default for security reasons)

I'm not much of a Windows person (less so a VBS person), so I wonder, whether it is even possible to register a font with VBS in the way I envision it.
If so, how?
Or are there easier way to register a font from within Tcl/Tk (or a shell).

Comment: Copy the file to `%windir%\Fonts`? I'm not sure whether you can add fonts without admin privileges, though.

Comment: Tcllib would be OK as that's implementable using pure Tcl code (**by design**); just copy the relevant files (or the code out of them) and you're good. However, the problem you're going to have (so far as I can tell from poking around web searches) is that you need to call `AddFontResourceEx` _in-process_ and running VBS in a subordinate process will therefore not let the parent process see the font. You need a tiny DLL (a dozen or so lines of code, virtually all of which is boilerplate) to do the registration.

Comment: @DonalFellows good point; i thought I could us `AddFontResourceEx` to register a font *per session* (rather than *private* per process); or call the Tcl/Tk application from within the VBS (so the font would be inherited from the parent process)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the extrafont package:
   https://wiki.tcl.tk/48903
This package will load external fonts without requiring them to 
be installed on the system.

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't meet the *pure Tcl/Tk solution* requirement (which I now see is probably too unclear...the point is that we really don't want a dependency on anything compiled or an interpreter that doesn't ship with a standard W32 installation)